# What is the "right" way in Angularjs of doing "master-detail" inter directive communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that displays a list of "master" items and when the user clicks on one of these items I want any "details" directives on the page (there could be more than one) to be updated with the details of the currently selected "master" item.

Currently I'm using id and href attributes as a way for a "details" directive to find its corresponding master directive. But my impression is that this is not the angular way, so if it's not, what would be a better solution?

I appreciate that typically when the issue of inter-communication between directives is raised then the obvious solutions are either to use require: "^master-directive" or to use a service, but in this case the directives are not in the same hierarchy and I don't think using a service is appropriate, as it would make the solution more complicated.

This is some illustrative code showing what I'm doing currently.

```
<div>                                                                                                                                      
  <master-list id="master1"></master-list>                                                                     
</div>                                                                                                                                                 
<div>                                                                                                                                
  <details-item href="#master1" ></details-item>                             
</div>
```

In the master-list directive when an item is selected I set an attribute to indicate the currently selected master item:

```
attrs.$set('masterListItemId',item.id);
```

In the details-item directive's link function I do:

```
if (attrs.href) {
  var id = attrs.href.split('#')[1];
  var masterList = angular.element(document.getElementById(id));                                                                             
  if (masterList) {
    var ctrl = masterList.controller('masterList');
    ctrl.attrs().$observe('masterListItemId',function(value) {
        attrs.$set('detailItemId',value);
    });
  }
}

attrs.$observe('detailItemId',function(id) {
    // detail id changed so refresh
});
```

One aspect that put me off from using a service for inter-directive communication was that it is possible (in my situation) to have multiple 'masterList' elements on the same page and if these were logically related to the same service, the service would end up managing the selection state of multiple masterList elements. If you then consider each masterList element had an associated detailItem how are the right detailItem elements updated to reflect the state of its associated masterList?

```
<div>                                                                                                                                      
  <master-list id="master1"></master-list>                                                                     
</div>                                                                                                                                                 
<div>                                                                                                                                      
  <master-list id="master2"></master-list>                                                                     
</div>                                                                                                                                                 
<div>                                                                                                                                
  <details-item href="#master1" ></details-item>                             
</div>                                                                                                                                                 
<div>                                                                                                                                
  <details-item href="#master2" ></details-item>                             
</div>
```

Finally I was trying to use directives, rather than using controller code (as has been sensibly suggested) as I'd really like the relationship between a masterList and its associated detailItems to be 'declared' in the html, rather than javascript, so it is obvious how the elements relate to each other by looking at the html alone.

This is particularly important as I have users that have sufficient knowledge to create a html ui using directives, but understanding javascript is a step too far.

Is there a better way of achieving the same thing that is more aligned with the angular way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would use a service for this. The service would hold the details data you care about, so it would look something like this.

In your `master-list` template, you might have something like a list of items:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat"item in items"><a ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

...or similar.

Then in your directives, you would have (partial code only)

```
.directive('masterList',function(DetailsService) {
   return {
     controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.select = function(item) {
         DetailsService.pick(item);  // or however you get and retrieve data
       };
     }
   };
})
.directive('detailsItem',function(DetailsService) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) { // you could do this in the link as well
      $scope.data = DetailsService.item;
    }
  };
})
```

And then use `data` in your details template:

```
<div>Details for {{data.name}}</div>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="detail in data.details">{{detail.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

Or something like that.

I would not use `id` or `href`, instead use a service to retrieve, save and pass the info.

EDIT:

Here is a jsfiddle that does it between 2 controllers but a directive would be the same idea
http://jsfiddle.net/u3u5kte7/

EDIT:
If you want to have multiple masters and details, leave the templates unchanged, but change your directive controllers and services as follows:

```
.directive('masterList',function(DetailsService) {
   return {
     controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.select = function(item) {
         DetailsService.pick($scope.listId,item);  // or however you get and retrieve data
       };
     }
   };
})
.directive('detailsItem',function(DetailsService) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) { // you could do this in the link as well
      $scope.data = DetailsService.get($scope.listId).item;
    }
  };
})
.factory('DetailsService',function(){
  var data = {};
  return {
    pick: function(id,item) {
      data[id] = data[id] || {item:{}};
      // set data[id].item to whatever you want here
    },
    get: function(id) {
      data[id] = data[id] || {item:{}};
      return data[id];
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: OK, so how would you ensure a 'detailsItem' directive is notified when an item in 'masterList' is selected? Also what if you had two 'masterList' directives on the same page each with a list of independently selectable items and each with a different set of associated 'detailItem' directives.

Comment: That's the beauty of the binding. You don't **need** to notify it. Because both use the `DetailsService`, when someone clicks on a master list item, which causes `select()` to run, which updates `DetailsService`, everything that depends upon it just updates.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the "two masterList" concept?

Comment: I've updated the question to try to illustrate multiple masterList elements.

Comment: You could easily expand the service to support multiple items. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for a different approach altogether without directives. Directives are ideal for DOM manipulation. But in this case I would stick to using just the template and a controller that manages all the data and get rid of the directives. Use ng-repeat to repeat the items

Check out this fiddle for an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/wbrand/2xrne4k3

template:

> ```
> <div ng-controller="ItemController as ic">
>     Masterlist:
>     <ul><li ng-repeat="item in ic.items" ng-click="ic.selected($index)">{{item.prop1}}</li></ul>
> ```

```
    Detaillist:
    <ul><li ng-repeat="item in ic.items" >
        {{item.prop1}} 
        <span ng-if="item.selected">SELECTED!</span>
     </li></ul>
</div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ItemController',function(){
this.items = [{prop1:'some value'},{prop1:'some other value'}]
this.selectedItemIndex;

this.selected = function(index){
    this.items.forEach(function(item){
        item.selected = false;
    })
    this.items[index].selected = true
}
})
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution, unfortunately I'd failed to mention that I was trying to construct such a ui without using any controllers, but simply by defining some html elements. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: why do you want that?

Comment: I've tried to explain the reasoning behind this in the modified question, namely I have users that understand how to put together UIs using html elements, but don't understand javascript.